# How to display YouTube like black title box?

Tags: html, css

I want to view black title box instead of regular title box like `<i class = "fa fa-eye" title = "Something"></i>` and I think there is readymade HTML tag for this as far I know because i have seen it somewhere else but couldn't remember at all! Please help me if you know the tag for this.
[image]

Above share button you can see a black box titled Share. I want to view that!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: That black title box is called tooltip. If you are using some framework like bootstrap this feature is inbuilt.

Comment: @Ihazkode I want to display black box when hover over an element like in thcse image you can see that black share box. It can be done via css but I would like to know if there is readymade HTML tag for it!

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik Got It!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: @Ihazkode Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w3schools has one as @Ihaz mentioned. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
  <h2>Top Tooltip w/ Bottom Arrow</h2>

  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

A creative one if needed;

```css
.wrapper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ececec;
  color: #555;
  cursor: help;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 100px 75px 10px 75px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  /* webkit flicker fix */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* webkit text rendering fix */
}

.wrapper .tooltip {
  background: #e84747;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  left: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
  -o-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}


/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */

.wrapper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid #e84747 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}


/* IE can just show/hide with no transition */

.lte8 .wrapper .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.lte8 .wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Subscribe
  <div class="tooltip">Subscribe to Channel</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Second one looks awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are Bootstrap tooltips. You can find the documentation here : [Bootstrap Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

If you include Bootstrap library you get easily modifiable and editable tooltips and many more things.